# PHP ZF2 - multiple sites with separate public folders

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to create a single ZF2 installation with multiple websites under it, with each site being a separate module. So far, with using Hostname routing, it works, except that all of the sites share the same public folder.

Is there a way to configure each module to have its own public folder?

I have seen some other questions about this, but they have mostly dealt with the routing itself or been ZF1 specific, which kept the public folder within the module.

Comment: Have you considered pointing each site's virtual host 'document root' to a separate folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quite easily do what you want:

- `site1.com`  document root: ~/project/site1/public
- `site2.com`  document root: ~/project/site2/public

`~/project/site1/public/index.php` and 
`~/project/site2/public/index.php` both contain:

```
<?php

// Set time zone.
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__.'../'));
chdir(dirname(__DIR__.'../'));

// Decline static file requests back to the PHP built-in webserver
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server' && is_file(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))) {
    return false;
}

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require '../config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many public folder as you want. Just put in index.php valid include of zf2 core and everything should work without any special modifications (what module to display can be specified by domain path or via global configuration you will put inside index.php).

Still I think is perfectly fine to have one public folder and change active modul per domain, also use some asset manager with configuration and content encapsulated inside module. Best for this is [rwoverdijk/AssetManager](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager).